# Writing a sequence of maps properly

Tags: arrows

I wanna write the sequence `$L \underset{\beta_1} \leftrightarrows \overset{ \alpha_1} M  \underset{\alpha_2} \leftrightarrows \overset{ \beta_2} N$`

with the map `\alpha_1` above the arrows and `\beta_1` below the arrows, same goes for `\alpha_2` and `\beta_2`.

Any help please?

Comment: @NicholasHamilton If you could please write my code in latex, you'd get exactly what I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
   $L \underset{\beta_1}{\overset{ \alpha_1} \leftrightarrow}  M
    \underset{\alpha_2}{\overset{ \beta_2} \leftrightarrow}  N$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to use `\longleftrightarrow` instead of `\leftrightarrow`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `mathtools` package's extensible arrows:

```
L \xleftrightarrow[\beta_1]{\alpha_1} M \xleftrightarrow[\alpha_2]{\beta_2} N
```